# Disable Result Count in Django ListView

Tags: python, django

I have a custom `ListView` whose query is rather expensive. When sub-queried for use in a `COUNT(*)`, the Postgres query planner does even worse in terms of performance. The count is about 20x slower than retrieving the results (46ms vs 922ms).

My question is is there a way to disable the count query for a subclass of `ListView`? In the Django admin, there is an option `show_full_result_count` which allows one to disable the extra `COUNT(*)` query for pagination. So is there a similar mechanism?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a custom paginator class that doesn't call `count()`, then set [`paginator_class`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-multiple-object/#django.views.generic.list.MultipleObjectMixin.paginator_class) on your view to use it.

```
class MyListView(ListView):
    paginator_class = MyPaginator
```

To write your own paginator class, you could try [this snippet](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2593/) or see the discussion on [this ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/8408).

Comment: @jack if you got this to work, what did your `MyPaginator` class look like? It might be useful for future readers.